# How to store a script in a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch script which I need to store somewhere, somehow,
I tried to use back quotes `` "`script here`" `` but it added escape character while using the string,
**I'm storing the script in the following way -**

```
sortByPriceScript : `"""
            double valueForComparision = 0;

            if(doc.currency.value == 'usd'){
                valueForComparision = doc.price.value;
            }
            else{
                if(params.isUsdCheckout){
                    valueForComparision = doc.price.value / params[doc.currency.value]["buy"];
                }
                else{
                    valueForComparision = doc.price.value / params[doc.currency.value]["spot"];
                }
            }
            return valueForComparision;     
        """`
```

**And it get's converted into -**

```
"\"\"\"\n            double valueForComparision = 0;\n\n            if(doc.currency.value == 'usd'){\n                valueForComparision = doc.price.value;\n            }\n            else{\n                if(params.isUsdCheckout){\n                    valueForComparision = doc.price.value / params[doc.currency.value][\"buy\"];\n                }\n                else{\n                    valueForComparision = doc.price.value / params[doc.currency.value][\"spot\"];\n                }\n            }\n            return valueForComparision;\t\t\n        \"\"\""
```

**How can I use the script in the following format -**

```
GET listings/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "constant_score": {
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{
                                "match": {
                                    "products_status": "1"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "match": {
                                    "show_listing": "true"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "script": {
                                    "script": {
                                        "source": "doc['forecast_quantity'].value > doc['minimum_quantity'].value",
                                        "params": {}
                                    }
                                }
                            }],
                            "should": [{
                                "term": {
                                    "seller_id": "1"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "term": {
                                    "seller_id": "2"
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "functions": [{
                "script_score": {
                    "script": {
                        "params": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "updated_at": 1565855175,
                            "usd": {
                                "buy": 1,
                                "sell": 1,
                                "spot": 1
                            },
                            "sgd": {
                                "buy": 0.72,
                                "sell": 0.72,
                                "spot": 0.72
                            },
                            "myr": {
                                "buy": 0.24,
                                "sell": 0.24,
                                "spot": 0.24
                            },
                            "inr": {
                                "buy": 0.014,
                                "sell": 1.014,
                                "spot": 0.014
                            },
                            "eur": {
                                "buy": 1.12,
                                "sell": 1.12,
                                "spot": 1.12
                            },
                            "isUsdCheckout": false
                        },
                        "source": """
            double valueForComparision = 0;

            if(doc.currency.value == 'usd'){
                valueForComparision = doc.price.value;
            }
            else{
                if(params.isUsdCheckout){
                    valueForComparision = doc.price.value / params[doc.currency.value]["buy"];
                }
                else{
                    valueForComparision = doc.price.value / params[doc.currency.value]["spot"];
                }
            }
            return valueForComparision;     
           """
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "sort": [{
        "_score": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }]
}
```

**It runs fine -**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triple quotes `"""` is only working in Kibana Dev Tools, you cannot use that in JavaScript code.

In your JS code, you can simply use the back ticks without the triple quotes:

```
esClient.search({
    index: 'index',
    size: 10,
    body: {
        query: {
            script: {
                script: {
                    source: `
                    double valueForComparision = 0;

                    if(doc.currency.value == 'usd'){
                        valueForComparision = doc.price.value;
                    }
                    else{
                        if(params.isUsdCheckout){
                            valueForComparision = doc.price.value / params[doc.currency.value]["buy"];
                        }
                        else{
                            valueForComparision = doc.price.value / params[doc.currency.value]["spot"];
                        }
                    }
                    return valueForComparision;     
                    `
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```